# Have a video collection on QNAP NAS and sometimes the files break.. Need advice

Tags: video, nas, qnap

Hello Superuser community! I have a question which I hope will be quick to answer.

I have a large video collection on a QNAP NAS and I find that sometimes the .mp4/.mkv video files will break and no longer play, with any programs. I had assumed that this was due to a virus perhaps, but I have no conclusive proof. I am using a QNAP 451+.

So my question is this:
Is there any tool that I can use to quickly check the playback success status of hundreds or thousands of videos?

I would like to investigate the files which won't work and try to piece together why this is happening.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Describing what you mean by break and inspecting such a broken file might help you. Do you have raid scrubbing enabled? Doing an automated test might be difficult depending on what kind of errors you're experiencing.

Comment: Sorry for that. For the files that are broken, they came from different sources (IE, some are ripped from DVD, some are not) and I discover that they are broken because my Win10 thumbnails view shows just a VLC icon and not an image from the video. When I open the files up in VLC, I do not get an error message, but the bottom tracker bounces left and right and eventually gives up. On some files, MPC-HC just gives me an error message "Cannot render this file."
I don't believe Raid Scrubbing is an option for my QNAP, because of the raid type.